# sIFR error when capturing page in Acrobat 9.1.2

Tags: sifr, acrobat

When using Adobe Acrobat Standard 9.1.2 and its built in Web site grabber, I end up with the following error in the PDF, “Rendered with sIFR 3, revision 436."

Is there a way to force Acrobat to render the plain text instead of the flash test?  Or a way to make sIFR compatible with the Acrobat site grabber?

Note the site displays fine in Firefox 3.5 and IE7.  Other forum posts have indicated this sort of error in a browser indicates a mismatch in sIFR and javascript versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with the way Acrobat captures web pages, but it sounds like it's trying to capture (or embed, who knows) the Flash movie directly, and failing. You might be able to detect Acrobat through a user agent string, and disable sIFR if it's looking at the page, but otherwise I'd consider this an Acrobat issue.

Comment: Interesting, the user agent for Acrobat 9.1.3 is coming up as "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/523.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Safari/523.15".

As all I need is a test site archive, I simply disabled sIFR (by renaming sifr.js) prior to the Acrobat pull.  As Acrobat messes with the layout anyways the missing fonts substitution isn't an issue.